# Problem programming in R: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object '"Recession' not found

Tags: r

I was wondering if you with your experience on R could help me.
I got this error: "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object '"Recession' not found". The problem is only to generate the **Pseudo R2**, for the rest of the code it is not problem.
my data: [Here is the data frame, which contains all the variables used in the regression, those are Recession, EPU, etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO5s3.png)

my code:

```
Regression_rep_OOS_Lag1 <- matrix(nrow = 29, ncol=6)
colnames(Regression_rep_OOS_Lag1) <- predictorlist
rownames(Regression_rep_OOS_Lag1) <- 1:29

Predicted_Rec_rep_OOS_Lag1_reg <- matrix(nrow=29, ncol=6)
colnames(Predicted_Rec_rep_OOS_Lag1_reg) <- predictorlist
rownames(Predicted_Rec_rep_OOS_Lag1_reg) <- 1:29

PseudoR2_rep_OOS_McFadden <- matrix(nrow=29, ncol=6)
colnames(PseudoR2_rep_OOS_McFadden) <- predictorlist
rownames(PseudoR2_rep_OOS_McFadden) <- 1:29

predictorlist<- list("EPU", "ENEWS", "Term.Spread", "Return.S.P500","Default.Spread", "VXO.index") 
i <- 1
for (j in predictorlist){
  for (i in 1:29){ 
  Regression_rep_OOS_Lag1 <- glm(paste("Recession ~", j[[1]]), family= binomial(link = "probit"),data = Ind_Var_Rep_out_lag_1[1:(78+i), ])
  Predicted_Rec_rep_OOS_Lag1_reg[i,j] <- predict(Regression_rep_OOS_Lag1, Ind_Var_Rep_out_lag_1[78+i, ], type = "response")
  PseudoR2_rep_OOS_McFadden[i,j] <- PseudoR2(Regression_rep_OOS_Lag1, which= "McFadden")

  }
}
```

I appreciate it any help.

Comment: To best help, please paste the output of the following function in your question: ```dput(data)``` , please do this for every data frame relevant.

Comment: Hi Glofa, please dput(data), it takes a bit more time but it also helps you to get your answer faster.. Looking at your code, I am guessing you need to do as.formula(paste("Recession ~", j[[1]]))

Comment: @ StupidWolf it was amazing your help. I could fix it. I have been trying to solve it  for about 2 weeks and nobody knew how to solve it. Thanks a lot. Now, My code is working perfectly... Thanks thanks...